# Get all records that do not have an empty field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

`Posts` have many `Comments`. Each `Comment` optionally belongs to a `User`.

How can I get all comments for Post 1 that HAVE a user?

```
Comments

content                           post_id    user_id 
-------                           -------    -------
There is no user for this post.   1
This is an example with a user.   1          123
Another example with a user.      1          8321
```

**Things I've tried:**

This returns no records

`@comments = Post.find(1).comments.where(:user_id != nil)`

These return every record:

```
@comments = Post.find(1).comments.where("user_id IS NOT NULL")

@comments = Post.find(1).comments.where("user_id <> 0")
```

When I print out the user_ids on the page, it looks like the nil ones are being read as "0", but are still null in the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments do
      def no_user 
         where.not(user_id: "") #-> http://robots.thoughtbot.com/activerecords-wherenot
      end
   end
end

#app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post
end
```

This will allow me to call:

```
#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def show
     @post = Post.find params[:post_id]
     @comments = @post.comments.no_user
  end
end
```

--

**Notes on Null**

Having `null` is a specific data-type in your database

We use it when wanting to "default" populate a table's columns - allowing you to submit no data, having the database be as efficient as possible in providing the right allocations of data.

I would certainly [look up about the `NULL` data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) with the likes of MYSQL & PGSQL. This will give you the ability to define any unpopulated data columns as `NULL` - allowing you to call the `NOT NULL` command.

Currently, your "non defined" data is just blank - not null

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have blank user_id column when comments doesn't have user. So the correct query should be

```
@post = Post.find(1)
@comments = @post.comments.where("user_id != ''")
```

Answer (score 0):

My code might not represent a standard way but it would work in both cases(Null and blank).

```
@post = Post.find(1)
@comments = @post.comments.where("user_id > 0")
```